# WebDriverException:can't load profile error in selenium python script

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver, web-testing

I am using selenium webdriver in python to drive Firefox automaticly, the python script is exported from the selenium IDE add-on in Firefox. But when I run the script it raise error:

```
        ======================================================================
    ERROR: test_selenium (__main__.SeleniumTest)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "selenium_test.py", line 8, in setUp
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 46, in __init__

        self.binary, timeout),
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 46,
    in __init__
        self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 44, in lau
    nch_browser
        self._wait_until_connectable()
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 87, in _wa
    it_until_connectable
        raise WebDriverException("Can't load the profile. Profile Dir : %s" % self.profile.path)
    WebDriverException: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir : c:\users\ataosky\appdata\local\temp\tmpwpz
    zrv

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 1 test in 67.876s

    FAILED (errors=1)
```

WebDriverException: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir : c:\users\ataosky\appdata\local\temp\tmpwpz

Have anybody encountered this problem? How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIE**:selenium 2.5 version has solve this problem.

Comment: Can we see the code?
I've run into similar issues in C#, but can't really tell you anything without seeing your code...

Comment: +1 - same issue with selenium 2.9.0. Suspect it may be related to the recent Firefox 8 upgrade.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this issue after upgrading to Firefox 8, when running selenium v 2.9.0.

It was fixed by **upgrading to the latest version of selenium** (2.13).

```
 sudo pip install selenium --upgrade
```

(if you're using the Python flavour)

Comment: I have the same issue, however I can't upgrade to Firefox 8 because of a bug in selenium 2.9+.  I'll have to downgrade to Firefox 7, issue I have is this auto-updated during a nightly test run and I have my firefox preference set prompt before upgrading

Comment: I've also just had this problem. Upgraded FF since last running selenium which was at v2.2. I've upgraded that to 2.24 and it executed firefox as the default profile & no errors.